# OpenJPA 0 or 1 JoinTable linkage

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

When attempting to utilize a unidirectional `OneToOne` or a `ManyToOne` relationship for a 0..1 relationship, OPENJPA is generating a INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN:

```
@OneToOne(optional=true, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="linkThisResult", 
    joinColumns= {
        @JoinColumn(insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false, name="thisid",referencedColumnName="thisid")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns= {
        @JoinColumn(insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false, name="resultid", referencedColumnName="resultid")
    }
)
private ResultEntity resultEntity;
```

given tables of :

```
result: { resultId, ... } 
this : { thisId, ... } 
linkThisResult: { linkThisResultId, resultId, thisId, ... }
```

None of the optional, insertable / updateable / nullable flags appear to affect the sql generated.   This is utilizing OPENJPA 2.2.0.  For direct JoinColumns without a JoinTable the optional does change the join type.

The question is: How to indicate to OPENJPA that the equivlent of a LEFT JOIN should be performed (ideally lazily but not a strict requirement)?

Comment: Can you please better phrase this in the form of a question

Comment: Added clarificationof implied question.

Comment: Thppt. Sorry - copy/paste of debugs in session. I'll correct the code above (optional was = true but tried opposite out of desperation).

Comment: What is the query you are using?  If it is JPQL, you must specify that  a left join is used within the from clause.  For example, "select a, resultEntity from MyEntity a left join a.resultEntity resultEntity where .."

Comment: I'm not using a jpql query, merely the getEntityManager().find(<id>, entityClassType).